# printing value from node

Tags: c, struct, nodes

I'm trying to go over a "bit string" which gives directions down a binary tree. The issue I'm having is printing the values from the node when it reaches the end (null) then returns to the top until a certain char in the "bit string" is hit at the end.

So the string:

```
char * directions = "RRLRRLRLLRLRRS";
```

would start at the root then go right>right>left>right (lets say that hits a leave) then it will go back to the root and traverse right>left>right>left>left (then switch back to the root every time a leaf is found then once it hits "S" it stops traversing.

The code I have now is now trying to get the values from the nodes it hits at the end for debug purposes and it's not printing anything. How can this be fixed?

(Order just helps determine where within the tree it is positioned)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node {
  int order;
  char value;
  struct Node * left;
  struct Node * right;
} Node;

Node * insert(Node * node, char value, int order){
  if(node == NULL){
    node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->value = value;
    node->order = order;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node;
  }
  if(order > node->order){
    node->right = insert(node->right, value, order);
  }
  else if(order < node->order){
    node->left = insert(node->left, value, order);
  }
  else {
    return;
  }
  return node;
}

int main(){


  Node * root = NULL;
  char * directions = "RRLRRLRLLRLRRS";
  int length = (int)strlen(directions);
  int i;

  root = insert(root, -1, 6);
  root = insert(root, -1, 4);
  root = insert(root, -1, 2);
  root = insert(root, 32, 1);
  root = insert(root, 114, 3);
  root = insert(root, 108, 5);
  root = insert(root, -1, 12);
  root = insert(root, -1, 8);
  root = insert(root, 111, 7);
  root = insert(root, -1, 10);
  root = insert(root, 101, 9);


  /* basics to see values at this point */
  i = 0;
  while(directions[i] != 'S'){
    if(directions[i] == 'L'){
      printf(root->value);
      root = root->left;
    }
    else if(directions[i] == 'R'){
      printf(root->value);
      root = root->right;     
    }
    i++;
  }

  return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seg faults if I try to run it as is, since you do not "reset" the root after hitting a leaf node. I modified  your printf statement to print out the actual int field of the Node struct and added an if-else to test if the current node in your traversal is a leaf:

```
  ...

  Node * origRoot = root;

  i = 0;
  while(directions[i] != 'S'){
    if(directions[i] == 'L'){
      printf("%d\n", root->order);
      if(root->left == NULL)
        root = origRoot;   
      else      
        root = root->left;
    }
    else if(directions[i] == 'R'){
      printf("%d\n", root->order);
      if(root->right == NULL)
        root = origRoot;   
      else      
        root = root->right;           
    }
    i++;
  }

  ...
```

I provide a visualization and step through the code here:  gist.github.com/liangricha/10337524

Comment: This doesn't return to the original root properly, then traverse properly again. and should be root->right in the last else :)